# Blazor Pass EventCallback as Class Property To Component

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to develop a component in Blazor and I would like it to get all its functionality (texts, EventCallbacks, etc) from a C# class. Something like this:

Blazor Component (Code Behind):

```
public partial class Card : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter] public CardData CardData { get; set; }

    protected async Task OnActionFiredEvent(EventCallback<object> eventCallback, object itemId)
    {
        if (eventCallback.HasDelegate)
            await CardData.CardTitleOnClickAction.InvokeAsync(itemId);
    }
}
```

Blazor Component (Razor):

```
<!-- Card image -->
<div class="view view-cascade overlay">
    <a>
        <div class="mask rgba-white-slight waves-effect waves-light"></div>
    </a>
</div>

<!-- Card content -->
<div class="card-body card-body-cascade text-center">

    <!-- Title -->
    <h4 class="card-title">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-light" @onclick="@(() => OnActionFiredEvent(CardData.CardTitleOnClickAction, CardData.CardItemId))">
            <strong>@CardData.CardTitle</strong>
        </a>
    </h4>
    <!-- Subtitle -->
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CardData.CardSubTitle))
    {
        <h6 class="font-weight-bold indigo-text py-2">@CardData.CardSubTitle</h6>
    }

    <!-- Text -->
    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CardData.CardText))
    {
        <p class="card-text">
            @CardData.CardText
        </p>
    }
</div>

<!-- Card footer -->
<div class="card-footer text-muted text-center">
    @CardData.CardFooter
</div>
```

CarData class:

```
public class CardData
{
    public object CardItemId { get; set; }
    public string CardTitle { get; set; }
    public string CardSubTitle { get; set; }
    public string CardText { get; set; }
    public string CardFooter { get; set; }
    public EventCallback<object> CardTitleOnClickAction { get; set; }
}
```

Use:

```
<Card CardData="@(new CardData() {
CardTitle = "TextTitle",
CardTitleOnClickAction = EventCallBackMethod,
CardSubTitle = "TextSubTitle",
CardText = "Text"})" />
```

The problem is that I get the following error when passing the EventCallBack as a class property:
**Cannot convert method group 'EventCallBackMethod' to non-delegate type 'EventCallback'. Did you intend to invoke the method?**

The method itself that is failing is something like this:

```
protected async Task EventCallBackMethod()
    {
        await DoSomething();
    }
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: EventCallback<object> your method should have a parameter of type object

Comment: Thanks for commenting @BrianParker, I've tried, as a test, the following code: CardTitleOnClickAction = EventCallBackMethod(1). But now I get the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback<object>'

Comment: could you make a simple sample project? It seems like that code should work or be really close.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by Brian Parker you need to have a type in your callback. If you don't want to pass a value you can pass `null`, for example;

**MyComponent.razor**

```
<button @onclick="OnButtonClicked">Click me</button>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback ButtonClicked{ get; set; }


    protected async Task OnButtonClicked()
    {
        await ButtonClicked.InvokeAsync(null);
    }
}
```

For example as a razor component, the button click triggers `OnButtonClicked`, which then invokes `ButtonClicked` parameter, which can be referenced in a parent page.

**Page.razor**

```
@page "/pagename"

<MyComponent ButtonClicked="@ButtonClickedHandler" />

@code{
    protected void ButtonClickedHandler()
    {
        Logger.LogInfo("Button click was handled on the page");
    }
}
```

---

If you want to pass parameters you can do so like follows;

**MyNextComponent.razor**

```
<button @onclick="OnButtonClicked">Click me</button>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool> ButtonClicked{ get; set; }

    protected async Task OnButtonClicked(bool value)
    {
        await ButtonClicked.InvokeAsync(true);
    }
}
```

**Page.razor**
@page "/pagename"

```
<MyNextComponent ButtonClicked="@ButtonClickedHandler" />

@code{
    protected void ButtonClickedHandler(bool value)
    {
        Logger.LogInfo($"Button click was handled on the page: {value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, however I don't think this answers the original question. I know how to do pass a EventCallback as a parameter to a Blazor component (as you show in here). What I do not know is how to pass that EventCallback Method as a property inside an object that acts as the parameter of the component

Comment: Have you tried moving this code into a "code behind" file? I would expect that to just work.

Comment: Yes, it's all in the code behind (.razor.cs) file the problem is that I've got a class CardData, with a property of type EventCallBack<object> and I don't know how to set that property with the method I want to execute when the user triggers the event in the component. Do not even know if it's possible

Comment: Are you trying to pass `CardData` back in the `EventCallback`, or pass nothing back?

Comment: CardData has an ItemId, when the event is fired I want only that Id. Something like this EventCallBackMethod.InvokeAsync(itemId) as in the code example I added under the label "Blazor Component (Code Behind)"

Comment: I think you are pretty much there. Make sure that your `[Parameter] EventCallback` parameter and the `Handler` method on your parent page both have the same parameter types.

Answer (score 1):

create your EventCallback like this

```
    private async Task Press1()
    {
        this.message = "F1";
    }

EventCallback evt1 = EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, Press1);
```

property

```
public class CardData
{
    public EventCallback<object> CardTitleOnClickAction { get; set; }
    public static EventCallback GetEvent(CardData data)
    {
        return data.CardTitleOnClickAction;
    }
}
```

compoment

```
@onclick="() =>Modal.CardData.GetEvent(data).InvokeAsync()"
```